# Constructing a function with desired properties

Tags: functions

I need to construct  a function $f(x,y)$ taking on continuous values between $0$ and $1$. $x$ and $y$ can take on any values (but their ranges may be restricted for convenience). This function should have the following properties:

1. When $x$ large and $y$ large, $f$ is small
2. When $x$ small and $y$ small, $f$ is small
3. When $x$ large and $y$ small, $f$ is large
4. When $x$ small and $y$ large, $f$ is large

I've been thinking of somehow using sines and cosines with different phase factors, but I don't know if this is the right approach. Any help is appreciated of course :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you mean by "x is small". If it means "close to zero", and thus x=100 and x=-100 both are not small, then this is works, for example:

$f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2)^2$

Example plot:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%5E2